# Scheduling multiple functions at different times of the day

Tags: date, youtube-api, settimeout, setinterval, timing

I'm trying to set up my code to show this youtube playlist from 12am to 12pm then show a different playlist from 12pm to 12am repeating the process. Ive looked at SetIntervals and Date but still pretty new to using java so not sure how to implement them. If anyone could give me an example to go off of I would appreciate it. Here is the current code I have

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }

    });
}
var oldNumber = 0;
var NewNumber = 0;

function newRandomNumber(min, max) {
    oldNumber = NewNumber;
    NewNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
    if (NewNumber == oldNumber) {
        newRandomNumber(min, max);
    } else {
        return NewNumber;
    }
}


function onPlayerReady(event) {
    next();

}

function next() {
    player.loadPlaylist({
        'listType': 'playlist',
        'list': 'PLBLjQxqJYmcdjxmoFURusJpwbKs0XTSOy',
        'autoplay': 1,
                'controls': 0,
        'index': newRandomNumber(0, 200),
    });
    player.setShuffle({
        'shufflePlaylist': true
    });
}


function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        next();
    }
}
</script>
```

here is the other playlist I've been trying to get it to change to

```
function next() {
player.loadPlaylist({
    'listType': 'playlist',
    'list': 'PLBLjQxqJYmcdjxmoFURusJpwbKs0XTSOy',
    'autoplay': 1,
            'controls': 0,
    'index': newRandomNumber(0, 200),
});
player.setShuffle({
    'shufflePlaylist': true
});
```

}

Comment: First off, that's not java, it's javascript. If you want to execute functions at a later time, you can use [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

Comment: Thought java and javascript were the same thing lol. Isn't setTimeout more of a timing thing instead of a scheduling? I can't get it to switch to the 2nd playlist at 12pm, instead it just runs for 12 hours.